# Nested List Group in Bootstrap 4

Tags: internet-explorer-11, bootstrap-4

The nested list groups in the code below work perfectly in Chrome, Edge and FireFox.  However, in IE11 the nested lists don't display properly.  If I use columns the text doesn't stay in the box.  If I don't use columns, the text runs off the screen.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.

```html
<div>
        <ul class="list-group">
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <strong>Group 1</strong>
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item col offset-1 col-11">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic.</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item col offset-1 col-11">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic.</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="list-group-item">
                <strong>Group 2</strong>
                <ul class="list-group">
                    <li class="list-group-item col offset-1 col-11">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic.</li>
                    <li class="list-group-item col offset-1 col-11">Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic.</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

EDIT 3-3-17
I think I might have got it working IE11 but then if failed the same way on an Apple with Safari.  So, I gave up on that approach and did:

```html
<div class="card-block">
 <p>Heading</p>
 <dl>
  <dt>Topic 1</dt>
  <dd>Item 1</dd>
  <dd>Item 2</dd>
 </dl>
 <dl>
  <dt>Topic 2</dt>
  <dd>Item 1</dd>
  <dd>Item 2</dd>
 </dl>
</div>
```

This works fine everywhere.  I suspect my problem may have something to do with the combination of BS4 and some CSS from a couple of other packages that I incorporated.  I just ran out of time and rewrote using Card.

Comment: The code you posted works fine consistently over all browsers you mentioned, at least for me.

Comment: Thanks for testing the code.  I've tried on a couple of my PCs and get the same problem on IE11??  Also, my IE11 is up to date.  I must have some other kind of conflict - thanks again.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Did you manage to fix it and how ?

Comment: @ChristopheLeBesnerais, please see my edit - hope it helps.

Comment: thanks. I fixed this by wrapping the text with another div, the list item looks like this now :

'

Comment: <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action flex-column align-items-start">
         <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
             <h5 class="mb-1">foo</h5>
         </div>
         <div class="d-flex w-100 justify-content-between">
            <p class="mb-1">bar</p>
         </div>
         </a>